# Error when looking up data source name when deploying httpServlet to weblogic 12 server

Tags: java, datasource, jndi, weblogic12c

I am trying to deploy an ear file to a Weblogic 12 server.  The ear file contains a HttpServlet.  During deployment, the HttpServlet is trying to initialize and fails with this error:

> Target state: deploy failed on Cluster 
>   javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: While trying to lookup
>   'jdbc.' didn't find subcontext 'jdbc'. Resolved
>   ''    at
>   weblogic.jndi.internal.BasicNamingNode.newNameNotFoundException(BasicNamingNode.java:1180)

I tested the data source connection on the weblogic servers and it is successful.

The data source is defined in a properties file that is being accessed because the datasource name is correct.  The webserver URL is also correct.

This is the init() method:

```
public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException
  {
    super.init(config);
    Context jndiContext = null;
    Hashtable ht = new Hashtable();
    try
    {
        PropertyManager.getInstance(PROPS_FILE);
        PropertyManager.getInstance();

        ht.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory");
        ht.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, PropertyManager.getProperty("WL_WEBSERVER_URL"));
        jndiContext = new InitialContext(ht);
        ds = (javax.sql.DataSource) jndiContext.lookup(PropertyManager.getProperty("SEC_DATASOURCE"));
    }
}
```

I don't understand why it does not recognize the subcontext of `jdbc`.
I tried removing `jdbc`. But the error is a NameNotFoundException without `jdbc`.

**UPDATE**
I tried changing the data source name to `java:jdbc/scantDS`.  I received a different NameNotFoundException:

> ". javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: While
>   trying to look up /jdbc/scantDS in /app/webapp/Load/421643657.;
>   remaining name '/jdbc/scantDS'    at
>   weblogic.jndi.internal.BasicNamingNode.newNameNotFoundException(BasicNamingNode.java:1180)

Comment: First, if the servlet is in the same server as the datasource you should get your initail context this way : Context jndiContext= new InitialContext();  
That's all you need. No need to use the hashtable.  
Next, check that your datasource is deployed in your server. Use the admin console, go to the server configuration page and click the "view JNDI tree" and check if your datasource is in the tree.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was trying to deploy using the wrong port number.  I was using the port number that the console application was using and I needed a specific port that has the JNDI.